# Creating Map of Maps using a custom Object as a reduction type in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have a `List<MyObject>`

```
class MyObject {
    String loanType;
    String loanCurrency;
    BigDecimal amountPaid;
    BigDecimal amountRemaining;
}
```

And I need to convert this *list* into a *map* `Map<String, Map<String, MySumObject>`.

I've created a custom `MySumObject` class because I need to get a *Sum* for both `amountPaid` and `amountRemaining` from the list of `MyObject` based on the `loanType` and `loanCurrency`.

```
class MySumObject {
    BigDecimal paidSum;
    BigDecimal remainingSum;
}
```

Using the code below, I can obtain a `Map<String,Map<String, BigDecimal>>`

```
Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>> result = list1.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(LoanObject::getLoanType,
        Collectors.groupingBy(LoanObject::getLoanCurrency,
            Collectors.reducing(
                BigDecimal.ZERO,
                LoanObject::getAmountPaid,
                BigDecimal::add)
        )
    ));
```

But I'm stuck on changing it to use `MySumObject` instead of `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MySumObject` as an accumulation type would make sense only if all the payment operation represented by `MyObject` in the source list belong to **different loans**.

Otherwise, there's a flow in your logic - *remaining amount* of a particular loan decreases after each payment. It's pointless to calculate the sum of *remaining amounts* of the **same** loan. Instead, we can grab the data regarding *remaining amount* from the *loan object* with the latest timestamp or having the lowest *remaining amount*, but that requires different strategy of grouping and different structure of *loan object* (`MyObject`), i.e. should have at least `loanId`.

That said, correctness of your logic - is your responsibility.

Let's get back to the initial idea of accumulating loans having the same currency and loan type into `MySumObject` (I assume that you know what you're doing, and it **does** make sense).

It can be achieved by creating a *custom collector* based on the `MySumObject`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, MySumObject>> result = list1.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyObject::getLoanType,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyObject::getLoanCurrency,
                Collector.of(
                    MySumObject::new,
                    MySumObject::addLoan,
                    MySumObject::merge
                ))
        ));
```

`MySumObject` with methods `addLoan()` and `merge()`.

```
public static class MySumObject {
    private BigDecimal paidSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal remainingSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    
    public void addLoan(LoanObject loan) {
        paidSum = paidSum.add(loan.getAmountPaid());
        remainingSum = remainingSum.add(loan.getAmountRemaining());
    }
    
    public MySumObject merge(MySumObject other) {
        paidSum = paidSum.add(other.getPaidSum());
        remainingSum = remainingSum.add(other.getRemainingSum());
        return this;
    }
    
    // getters, constructor, etc. are omitted
}
```

**Sidenote:** it doesn't seem to be justifiable to use a string to represent a currency (*unless it's not an assignment requirement*) because since Java 1.4 we have a class [`Currency`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html).

Comment: How to set the initialize value for those two fields in MySumObject? Otherwise, it will throw NPE.

Comment: @yulinxp That's a good point. In order to use `MySumObject` as a *mutable container*, by default, these fields should be initialized with a value of `BigDecimal.ZERO`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the nested map via `groupingBy` you would normally end up with a list of `MyObject`.  But you want to sum those values so you need to use `CollectingAndThen` with a `finisher`.  In this case the finisher streams each list and applies a reduction to build the final object. In my solution I simply created a new `MySumObject` each time, adding the previouly computed MySumObject, to the next `MyObject` value from the list. This method is quite common and has advantages in that it also works with immutable containers such as `records` and does not require additional modification to your classes outside of the standard getters used to retrieve the fields. To avoid clutter, I created a helper method to do the reduction. But the actual summation code could have been put in the collector.

```
Map<String, Map<String, MySumObject>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                MyObject::getLoanType,
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        MyObject::getLoanCurrency,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.toList(),
                                lst->summing(lst)))));
```

Helper method to reduce the list to a single object.  Since the reduction works on two different types, the three argument version of reduce is used.  First the target `MySumObject` is initialized with zero sums. Then the reduction creates the new `MySumObject` and adds each appropriate `MyObject` to it. The third argument would be used for parallel processing to sum the different `MySumObjects` from different threads.  In this case, I just assigned the already computed value assuming a single stream.

```
public static MySumObject summing(List<MyObject> list) {
    return list.stream()
    .reduce(new MySumObject(
            BigDecimal.ZERO,
            BigDecimal.ZERO),
            (MySumObject mySum, MyObject myOb) -> new MySumObject(
                    myOb.getAmountPaid()
                            .add(mySum.getPaidSum()),
                    myOb.getAmountRemaining()
                            .add(mySum.getRemainingSum())),(a,b)->a);
}
```

As an alternative, you could also do it like this which I believe would be more efficient since you are summing as each `MyObject` is referenced.  It takes advantage of the Java 8+ map enhancements.  [ComputeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) creates the value if the key is missing.  It will return that value or the existing one.  Since that value is also a map, [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) can be applied.  That will also create the value if the key is missing or process the existing value.

```
Map<String, Map<String, MySumObject>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (MyObject mo : list) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(mo.getLoanType(),
            v -> new HashMap<String, MySumObject>())
            .compute(mo.getLoanCurrency(),
                    (k, v) -> v == null ?
                            new MySumObject(
                                    mo.getAmountPaid(),
                                    mo.getAmountRemaining()) :
                            new MySumObject(
                                    v.getPaidSum().add(mo
                                            .getAmountPaid()),
                                    v.getRemainingSum().add(mo
                                            .getAmountRemaining())));
}
```

For the following data, the output is shown and would be identical for both methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> list = List.of(
            new MyObject("Type1", "Currency1",
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(10),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(100)),
            new MyObject("Type2", "Currency2",
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(20),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(200)),
            new MyObject("Type1", "Currency1",
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(30),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(300)),
            new MyObject("Type2", "Currency2",
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(40),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(400)));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Type2={Currency2=MySumObject[getPaidSum=60, getRemainingSum=600]}
Type1={Currency1=MySumObject[getPaidSum=40, getRemainingSum=400]}
```

Comment: For summing() method, how does combiner (a,b)->a work? Does it need something like (mySumObject1, mySumObject2) -> { mySumObject1.setPaidSum(mySumObject1.getPaidSum().add(mySumObject2.getPaidSum()));...return mySumObject1;}

Comment: Exactly.  A and B are the same type.  So if you were doing this in parallel that would be the combiner to add the individual sums from the different threads.  BTW, If I thought you wanted a different solution I would have provided it.  I was just trying to address your immediate problem as you asked it without adding special methods to your classes.