# Java-Stream - Abnormal behaviour while using Collector reducing()

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to solve the problem described in the following question using *collector* `reducing()`:

[Creating Map of Maps using a custom Object as a reduction type in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299786/creating-map-of-maps-using-a-custom-object-as-a-reduction-type-in-java-8/73300611?noredirect=1#comment129496249_73300611)

We need to obtain a `Map<String,Map<String,MySumObject>>` as a result by adding up `BigDecimal` amounts of *loan objects* represented by `MyObject` while grouping the data by `loanType` then `loanCurrency`.

*Dummy classes:*

```
class MyObject {
    String loanType;
    String loanCurrency;
    BigDecimal amountPaid;
    BigDecimal amountRemaining;
}

class MySumObject {
    BigDecimal paidSum;
    BigDecimal remainingSum;
}
```

Based on Alexander Ivanchenko's solution (*see the link to original question*) using

```
Collector.of(
    MySumObject::new,
    MySumObject::addLoan,
    MySumObject::merge
)
```

Firstly, I've changed it in the following way:

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(MyObject::getLoanType,
    groupingBy(MyObject::getLoanCurrency,
        Collector.of(
            MySumObject::new,
            (mySumObject, myObject) -> {
                mySumObject.setPaidSum(mySumObject.getPaidSum().add(myObject.getAmountPaid()));
                mySumObject.setRemainingSum(mySumObject.getRemainingSum().add(myObject.getAmountRemaining()));
            },
            (mySumObject1, mySumObject2) -> {
                mySumObject1.setPaidSum(mySumObject1.getPaidSum().add(mySumObject2.getPaidSum()));
                mySumObject1.setRemainingSum(mySumObject1.getRemainingSum().add(mySumObject2.getRemainingSum()));
                return mySumObject1;
            })
        )
    ));
```

Then I was trying to make it working using *collector* `reducing()`.

But it appears that it **adds up everything** together regardless of `groupingBy()`. Not sure which part is wrong:

```
List<MyObject> list = List.of(
    new MyObject("Type1", "Currency1", BigDecimal.valueOf(10), BigDecimal.valueOf(100)),
    new MyObject("Type1", "Currency1", BigDecimal.valueOf(10), BigDecimal.valueOf(100)),
    new MyObject("Type2", "Currency2", BigDecimal.valueOf(20), BigDecimal.valueOf(200)),
    new MyObject("Type3", "Currency3", BigDecimal.valueOf(30), BigDecimal.valueOf(300)),
    new MyObject("Type4", "Currency4", BigDecimal.valueOf(40), BigDecimal.valueOf(400))
);

list.stream().collect(groupingBy(MyObject::getLoanType,
    groupingBy(MyObject::getLoanCurrency,
        reducing(new MySumObject(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO),
            (myObject) -> new MySumObject(
                myObject.getAmountPaid(),
                myObject.getAmountRemaining()
            ),
            (mySumObject1, mySumObject2) -> {
                mySumObject1.setPaidSum(mySumObject1.getPaidSum().add(mySumObject2.getPaidSum()));
                mySumObject1.setRemainingSum(mySumObject1.getRemainingSum().add(mySumObject2.getRemainingSum()));
                return mySumObject1;
            })
        )
    ));
```

Here is the output it produces. All the values are added together, which is incorrect.

```
Type2={Currency2=MySumObject(paidSum=110, remainingSum=1100)}
Type3={Currency3=MySumObject(paidSum=110, remainingSum=1100)}
Type4={Currency4=MySumObject(paidSum=110, remainingSum=1100)}
Type1={Currency1=MySumObject(paidSum=110, remainingSum=1100)}
```

Comment: Updated description for result Map<String,Map<String, MySumObject>>. @AlexanderIvanchenko Yes, your solution works. I just want to see how to get it working using reducing.

Comment: Ok, you want to use only collectors `groupingBy` and `reducing()` for that problem, right? That's a valid independent question. But what about my *first* comment, I don't see clear reason to manipulate the data via setters. Can you clarify that point.

Comment: Updated description on what I am trying to learn from the original ticket. I can't put code in proper format in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operation `reduce()` is meant folding the stream by performing reduction on immutable objects (the same holds true for collector `reducing()`). On the other hand, `collect()` operation is meant for performing mutable reduction.

The observed caused by mixing the two approaches together - you're mutating the *identity* instead of returning a *new object*. That not how reduce should function.

As a result, all the entries of the nested Map would hold the reference to the **same value**. That would an instance of `MySumObject` provided as the identity of reduction. ***Reminder:*** `reducing()` as its first argument *identity* of type `U` (not a `Supplier`), hence only a single *identity* object would be created (you can print a message from the constructor to make sure that it would be fired only once).

In order to apply collector `reducing()` for solving this problem you need to change the reduction logic instead of mutating the *identity*, every step of reduction should produce a new `MySumObject`.

For that, we need to change the third argument of `reducing()`, which is `BinaryOperator<U>` used for combining the two instances of `MySumObject`.

And it would be more handy to introduce a mapper method in the `MyObject` class.

***Sidenote:** try to use more meaningful names. It makes it easier to work with the code. For instance, `Loan` instead of `MyObject`, `LoanSum` instead of `MySumObject`.*

That's how it might be implemented:

```
Map<String, Map<String, MySumObject>> result = list1.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyObject::getLoanType,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyObject::getLoanCurrency,
            Collectors.reducing(
                new MySumObject(),
                MyObject::toMySum,
                MySumObject::merge
            ))
    ));
```

`MySumObject` class with a `merge()` method which returns a new object:

```
public static class MySumObject {
    private BigDecimal paidSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal remainingSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    
    public void addLoan(MyObject loan) {
        paidSum = paidSum.add(loan.getAmountPaid());
        remainingSum = remainingSum.add(loan.getAmountRemaining());
    }
    
    public MySumObject merge(MySumObject other) {
        BigDecimal newPaidSum = paidSum.add(other.getPaidSum());
        BigDecimal newRemainingSum = remainingSum.add(other.getRemainingSum());
        return new MySumObject(newPaidSum, newRemainingSum);
    }
    
    // AllArgs & NoArgs constructors, getters, etc.
}
```

`MyObject` class with mapper method `toMySum()`:

```
public static class MyObject {
    private String loanType;
    private String loanCurrency;
    private BigDecimal amountPaid;
    private BigDecimal amountRemaining;
    
    public MySumObject toMySum() {
        return new MySumObject(this.amountPaid, this.amountRemaining);
    }
    
    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tQK)